# Can i build up some wiki/ google doc type editor by php???

Tags: wiki

it seems that the google doc/wiki is difficult if i code it from the zero
So, are there any kinds of api/plugin already have those code for php.
Also, how can wiki handle the parallel editing?? Say, one have update the content when the other one is updating. How can the latter one get the most updated information ????
Otherwise the updated content will be erase once the latter one submit update .

Thanks

Comment: There are lots of open source php based wiki out there. The technology you are looking for to enable live editing by multiple authors is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Comment: thx, can you also kindly suggest some php which implemented google doc kind editing ?

Comment: Sorry not aware of any php library that does that. But if you read up the link above and search around some more about the technology, you should be able to find a way to implement it using a combination of php on the server and javascript on the editing page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the first part of your question, but as for the parallel editing:

It seems to me that you're basically coding a CMS system. As with most CMSs (CMSii?), you're going to want every article to have two possible states: checked in or checked out. That way, you eliminate the possibility of 2 people working on the same article simultaneously.

So basically, in your database table that holds your article entries, you'd want a row called something like `checked_out`, which defaults to `0`.

When an editor clicks to edit an article, your code first checks to make sure `checked_out == 0`. That way it knows you're the only one working on that particular article. Then, if it does allow you to work on the article, set `checked_out` to `1`. When you click to save/update/whatever the article, make sure it sets `checked_out` back to `0`.

Seems like the simplest solution to me.

Comment: the problem is wiki allow user to working on the same article simultaneously? And how can they prevent the conflict ?? thanks